# JQUERY How to add class with text inside element

Tags: jquery, addclass

It's possible with jquery add class with the content of p?

```
<p>red</p>
<p>blue</p>
<p>green</p>
```

like

```
<p class="red">red</p>
<p class="blue">blue</p>
<p class="green">green</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
$('p').each(function () {
    this.className = this.textContent; //get the text within the element and set it as class name
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5phjf/1/)

In Fiddle, check console.log for the output.

**Note:** `.innerHTML` can be used but it is better to use `.textContent` when dealing with only text.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("p").addClass(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text());
});
```